# no named parameter with the name home

Tags: flutter

[image]

```
   bodyText1: TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(20, 51, 51, 1)
              ),
         bodyText2: TextStyle(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(20, 51, 51, 1)
            ),
    title: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 24,
    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
    )

      ),
    home:   Categories(),
    ),
      );
```

Comment: If you indent your code properly (Ctrl-Alt-L or Cmd-Opt-L) it will be easy to see what is wrong.

Comment: `home` is a parameter of `MaterialApp`. And you are passing it to `ThemeData`. Move that parameter out into the `MaterialApp`.

Comment: move the home parameter outside of that parenthesis, you're writing it in theme data

Comment: Please add the whole source code

Answer (score 1):

ThemeData has no home parameter. You probably meant to put the line below the next closing parenthesis, so it applies to MaterialApp